# OpenConnect cannot connect to VPN server: refreshes wait.html forever

Tags: linux, networking, vpn

In the past I could connect to a certain Cisco VPN server. I've been away travelling for 7 weeks, and now I'm back home, but no longer able to connect to the VPN server. Today the server suddenly asks me to run a 'Cisco Secure Desktop' trojan, and I've configured OpenConnect to do this (both via a GUI dialog, and the `--csd-user` command line option to `openconnect`), still I'm no longer able to get the VPN connection working.

The VPN connection log ends with these four lines repeated over and over again:

```
GET https://vpn.server.com/+CSCOE+/sdesktop/wait.html
SSL negotiation with vpn.server.com
Connected to HTTPS on vpn.server.com
Refreshing +CSCOE+/sdesktop/wait.html after 1 second...
```

Do you have any idea about what's happening or how I can fix this?

Would you guess that the problem is a VPN server side configuration change? The 'Cisco Secure Desctop' script perhaps? The VPN server has never asked me to run the 'Cisco Secure Desktop' script before, when I was able to connect. — Or do you think my OS has upgraded OpenConnect to a somehow incompatible version?

*"Refreshing .../sdesktop/wait.html"*, what's that, why? And *+CSCOE+*, sounds weird.

My OS: Linux Mint 17. OpenConnect version v5.02. Other people are able to connect to the VPN server — they use Mac or Windows, not Linux, though.

Here's the full OpenConnect log:

```
POST https://vpn.server.com/
Attempting to connect to server 111.222.333.444:443
Using client certificate 'My-Full-Name'
Adding supporting CA 'TC TrustCenter Class 2 L1 CA XI'
SSL negotiation with vpn.server.com
Connected to HTTPS on vpn.server.com
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.0 302 Object Moved
GET https://vpn.server.com/
Attempting to connect to server 111.222.333.444:443
SSL negotiation with vpn.server.com
Connected to HTTPS on vpn.server.com
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.0 302 Object Moved
GET https://vpn.server.com/+webvpn+/index.html
SSL negotiation with vpn.server.com
Connected to HTTPS on vpn.server.com
GET https://vpn.server.com/CACHE/sdesktop/install/binaries/sfinst
GET https://vpn.server.com/+CSCOE+/sdesktop/wait.html
Refreshing +CSCOE+/sdesktop/wait.html after 1 second...
GET https://vpn.server.com/+CSCOE+/sdesktop/wait.html
SSL negotiation with vpn.server.com
Connected to HTTPS on vpn.server.com
Refreshing +CSCOE+/sdesktop/wait.html after 1 second...
GET https://vpn.server.com/+CSCOE+/sdesktop/wait.html
SSL negotiation with vpn.server.com
Connected to HTTPS on vpn.server.com
Refreshing +CSCOE+/sdesktop/wait.html after 1 second...
GET https://vpn.server.com/+CSCOE+/sdesktop/wait.html
SSL negotiation with vpn.server.com
Connected to HTTPS on vpn.server.com
Refreshing +CSCOE+/sdesktop/wait.html after 1 second...
GET https://vpn.server.com/+CSCOE+/sdesktop/wait.html
SSL negotiation with vpn.server.com
Connected to HTTPS on vpn.server.com
Refreshing +CSCOE+/sdesktop/wait.html after 1 second...
(... continues forever)
```

I read [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1172567#p1172567) that I could wrap the 'Cisco Secure Desktop' script in a shell script, via the `--csd-wrapper` option; the suggested script looks like so:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
exec 2>&1 > /dev/null
CSD_BINARY="$1"
shift
$CSD_BINARY "$@"
```

This didn't have any effect though.

I've also tested the `--no-xmlpost` flag, as suggested [here](http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/openconnect-devel/2013-July/001119.html), no effect.

[Someone suggest](http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/openconnect-devel/2013-July/001117.html) to install 32 bit support, but apparently my OS already has that:

```
$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
```

[Here](http://nerdanswer.com/answer.php?q=327709) is someone else who has encountered the same problem. It's a ServerFault question, but it was apparently deleted at ServerFault, off-topic over there I'd guess. There were no answers to the question.

---

**Edit** With the `-v` (verbose) flag, `openconnect` keeps repeating these lines:

```
$ openconnect -v -c cert.pem --csd-user=kajmagnus vpn.example.com
...
GET https://vpn.example.com/+CSCOE+/sdesktop/wait.html
SSL negotiation with vpn.example.com
Connected to HTTPS on vpn.example.com
Got HTTP response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Close
Date: Thu, 06 Nov 2014 11:10:18 GMT
HTTP body chunked (-2)
Refreshing +CSCOE+/sdesktop/wait.html after 1 second...
```

Comment: I just posted this question to the OpenConnect mailing list too: http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/openconnect-devel/2014-November/002370.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the VPN server has been modified to no longer support Linux, and all old certificates have been invalidated, I just found out.

So I think there were two problems causing the weird error messages: 1) Linux not supported, and 2) wrong certificate.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but was able to get my Fedora Core 25 machine to connect to work's VPN by following an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815145/ubuntu-16-04-openconnect-cisco-vpn-failed-to-obtain-webvpn-cookie) given on Ask Ubuntu.  I know this is an old question, but since it still comes up early in search engines, I wanted to post something that forwards to a solution.

Unless you edited the output from openconnect, your problem might have been that you followed the examples too closely.  You were trying to connect to "vpn.example.com" instead of your corporate VPN server.

Comment: Hi David, actually I've posted an answer on this page already, clarifying what turned out to be the problem in my case, here: https://superuser.com/a/836703/95772 (the problem was _not_ typing `example.com` literally — the reason I edited the output, is I didn't want the name of the related company to appear in this question)

Comment: I saw your answer, but since I had the same output as you had (albeit a different server), I was hoping that the link I provided would help you, like it helped me.  Even if it doesn't, it may help other people like me who get the same output as you got, but whose AnyConnect server is compatible with GNU/Linux.  For what it's worth, I switched my functional csd-wrapper.sh to match what you used and got the same output as you.  It's possible that the openconnect team fixed something in the intervening two years.